# Neo4J: How could I restart the database from the cypher-shell?

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher, restart, cypher-shell

How could I restart the Neo4J database using the cypher-shell?

Do you Know if exist a command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The answer is: you can't restart Neo4j through cypher.**

What your options are if you use Neo4j as a Service:

- [Windows](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/windows/#windows-service) aka (cd to the right directory) `neo4j restart`
- [Linux](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/linux/systemd/#linux-service-control) aka `systemctl restart neo4j`

Comment: `neo4j restart` works also in docker container